# Finding a substitution for the integral of $\frac{dx}{2\sqrt{x+3}+x}$

Tags: calculus

The question wants me to make a substitiution to express $\frac{dx}{2\sqrt{x+3}+x}$ as a rational function and then evaluate. I tried a few different $u's$ (such as $\sqrt{x+3}$ and $2\sqrt{x+3}+x$, but I can never seem to get all of the $x's$ gone. I'm left with $\frac{1}{2u+x}$, which I don't know if it is allowed.

What should I put as the substitution?

Comment: Well, if you let $u=\sqrt{x+3}$, you can note for a start that $x=u^2-3$. You'll also need to replace the $\,dx$ by a $\frac{dx}{du} \,du$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes with substitution problems there's an extra "rearrangement" step you have to do.  Here's a simpler example:

$$
\int x^3 \sqrt{x^2 + 1} \: dx
$$
If you make the substitution $u = x^2 + 1$ (picking a radical or something under a radical is often a good first guess), you'll turn the integral into
$$
\frac{1}{2} \int x^2 \sqrt{u} \: du.
$$
In order to get rid of the last $x^2$, you must go back and rearrange your original substitution rule:
$$
u = x^2 + 1 \implies u - 1 = x^2
$$
and plug that in:
$$
\frac{1}{2} \int (u - 1) \sqrt{u} \: du.
$$
Now the integral can be solved using the power rule.

Returning to your original problem, you have
$$
\int \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+3} + x} \: dx
$$
and if you make the substitution $u = \sqrt{x+3}$ ($\implies$ $du = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+3}} dx$), you have the rearrangements
$$
u^2 - 3 = x \quad \text{and} \quad dx = 2 \sqrt{x+3} \: du = 2u\:du.
$$